# Why is partial class template argument deduction impossible?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction, ctad

My understanding about the [*P0091: Template argument deduction for class templates*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r3.html) proposal was to homogenize the behavior of function templates and class templates in deduction contexts, but I think that I have misunderstood something.

If we have this class template:

```cpp
template <std::size_t S, typename T>
struct test
{
    static constexpr auto size = S;
    using type_t = T;

    test(type_t (&input)[size]) : data(input) {}
    type_t (&data)[size]{};
};
```

I tend to use a helper function as *syntactic sugar* for creating `test` objects:

```cpp
template <std::size_t S, typename T>
test<S, T> helper(T (&input)[S]) { return input; }
```

Which can be used as shown below:

```cpp
int buffer[5];

auto a = helper<5, int>(buffer); // No deduction
auto b = helper<5>(buffer);      // Type deduced
auto c = helper(buffer);         // Type and size deduced
```

The code above compiles. I've tried the same in Wandbox using the newer compiler setup<sup>1</sup>:

```cpp
int buffer[5];

test<5, int> a(buffer); // No deduction: OK.
test<5> b(buffer);      // Type deduced: FAILS.
test c(buffer);         // Type and size deduced: OK.
```

It looks like template argument deduction for class templates works only deducing all the parameters. I was expecting both behaviors (helper function and class template) to be the same; have I misunderstood something?

---

<sup>1</sup>The last compilers availables in Wandbox are *gcc HEAD 7.0.1 201701* and *clang HEAD 5.0.0 (trunk)*.

Comment: Is `type_t (&data)[size]{};` an array reference? Is the `{}` an initializer? Does that compile? Also, *sintactic sugar* sounds pretty naughty. :)

Comment: Note that [adding an explicit *deduction guide*](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VEE5DyIE3w3LEGEX) does not help. I believe that partial deduction is not supported as the standard defines a deduction placeholders in terms of a *template name* *(i.e. with no `<...>` syntax)*. Therefore `test<5>` is not a valid deduction placeholder.

Comment: @Muscampester `type_t (&data)[size]{};` is an array reference, yes. The `{}` is indeed the initializer, and it compiles [try it out!](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KCkDg5EEIKbZbPU3). About *sintactic sugar* what can I say... :'( english is not my mother tonghe and I do lots of mistakes!

Comment: From what I remember, it was deemed undesirable to have something like `tuple<int> t{5, nullptr};` be accepted.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From this excellent [trip report](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2016/07/06/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-oulu-june-2016/) by Botond Ballo:

> The feature as originally proposed included a provision for partial deduction, where you explicitly specify some of the template arguments, and leave the rest to be deduced, but this was pulled over concerns that it can be very confusing in some cases:
>
> ```
> // Would have deduced tuple<int, string, float>,
> // but tuple<int> is a well-formed type in and of itself!
> tuple<int> t(42, "waldo", 2.0f);
> ```

Comment: I find this reasoning very weird. So first of all we've had `std::make_tuple<int> (42, "waldo", 2.0f);` doing supposedly the wrong thing all along and taught people that it's wrong to specify template arguments when they are deduced. Now by forbidding this, we make deduction for class template to work in different way as the function one (inconsistency) and block a ton of valid use cases (different from contrived tuple example).

Comment: @Predelnik: The problem is that existing code could use `A<T,U> a(t,u,v)` with a default template argument for `V` (or an argument pack of length 2 rather than 3).  You dare not silently change such a meaning that _depends_ on what was a perfectly reliable _lack_ of deduction.  Maybe if you had only explicit deduction guides, it would be OK, but with the implicit ones it’s too dangerous.

Comment: @DavisHerring Yes breaking existing code seems to be a much better reason, it's still sad to not be able to apply it for sane use cases.

Comment: Might consider adding placeholder syntax `tuple<int, _, _> t(42, "waldo", 2.0f);`

Answer (score 18):

There appears to be a contradiction here. Looking at [P0091R3](http://wg21.link/P0091R3), it seems clear that partially specifying parameters is supposed to be allowed:

> We propose to allow a template name referring to a class template as a simple-type-specifier or **with partially supplied explicit template arguments** in two contexts:

But the *actual standards wording* in the same proposal does not provide a way to handle "partially supplied explicit template arguments". `template-name` as a simple-type-specifier is not allowed to have template arguments.

So following the specification itself, the compiler's behavior appears to be correct.

Comment: Yes, that paper in particular is a rather egregious case of the author failing to keep the introductory parts in sync as the wording and the design are revised. The result is an actively misleading introductory section, unfortunately.

Comment: Good thing they have another meeting before they want to have the final vote.

Comment: @MikelF: You assume that they will actually allow partial specification. The incongruity in the writing suggests that this was something the committee elected to *remove*, rather than the original writer simply making a mistake in his wording.

Comment: @NicoBolas What I actually assume (or at least hope) is that they will make it consistent.

Comment: At the very least, it might be worth informing the authors that the current implementation breaks things.