# Why didn't the C++17 standard bring partial class template argument deductions?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

One of the places I hoped I would be able to use the new template argument deduction, was in construction of `std::set`'s / `std::map`s / any other containers with custom comparators - my goal is to create a one-line statement, that will create an efficient set with a lambda comparator.
What I can do since C++11 is:

```
std::set<int, std::function<bool(int, int)>> s([](int a, int b) {return a > b;});
```

But since it uses `std::function`, it is noticeably slower.

Another option is:

```
auto mycomp = [](int a, int b) {return a > b; };
std::set<int, decltype(mycomp)> s(mycomp);
```

It gets the job done, but 1) It requires 2 lines, and creation of the `mycomp` variable 2) I need to pass `mycomp`'s type explicitly.

As I read on reference pages, none of the standard containers has a deduction guide for this kind of situation. Unfortunately, I'm afraid it cannot be even done with the current language standard (C++17), as one can find:

> Class template argument deduction is only performed if no template argument list is present. If a template argument list is specified, deduction does not take place.

What is the reasoning behind this? Why didn't they allow partial argument deduction? I guess there are some problems with it that I overlook, but in my opinion it would be more than helpful.

Comment: Partial deduction was in proposal first, but has been removed. See [c17-class-template-partial-deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833630/c17-class-template-partial-deduction)

Comment: @Kaznov: "*my goal is to create one-line statement, that will create efficient set with lambda comparator.*" ... why is that your goal? What's wrong with just creating a struct with an `operator()` overload? Why do you *have to* (or even *want to*) use lambdas?

Answer (score 11):

As alternative, you can still make the old `make_xxx`

```
template <typename T, typename COMP>
std::set<T, COMP> make_set(COMP comp)
{
    return std::set<T, COMP>{comp};
}


auto s = make_set<int>([](int a, int b) {return a > b; });
```

Answer (score 11):

In one line (C++17)

```
std::set s(std::initializer_list<int>{}, [](int a, int b) {return a > b; });
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of this constructor existance. Well, it solves the problem with containers.

Comment: @Kaznov - works but is not really elegant: that `std::initializer_list<int>{}`, just to explicit the `int` type, is very ugly.

Answer (score 5):

What you should be doing is writing a comparator functor type, so you don't need to proxy to it when using your set. It will be a lot more lines of code (the atrocity!), but is better in virtually every way:

```
struct MyComparator
{
    bool operator()(int a, int b) const { ...; }
};
using MySet = std::set<int, MyComparator>;
```

And from then on, you'd just create your customly sorted set where you need it.

Comment: I know this is the best way of solving this problem, but I was looking for the most compact one.

Comment: @Kaznov: Why does it need to be compact? Having a big lambda in the middle of a template specialization doesn't make your code easier to read. This less "compact" is far easier to read than the lambda.

Comment: I was looking for the fastest way of doing this, to use it on algorithmic competition. There you don't care how the code looks like, the shorter the better.

Answer (score 0):

Because of ambiguity it brings when template parameter with default value are present. Also, in case of variadic templates.