# Deduction of templated class member in templated class

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, member

I am taking advantage of C++17 new feature to deduce the class member type in a templated class. Specifically, I am doing this:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t N = 0>
class A
{
public:
    using Array = std::array<int, N>;

    A(const Array& arr) : myArr{arr} {}
    A() = default;

    void show() { std::cout << N << std::endl; }

private:
    Array myArr;
};
```

When I construct `A` without indicating `N` explicitly, compiler matches correctly the constructor and deduces `N` correctly!

```
std::array<int, 3> data{1, 2, 3};
A a1{data};
A a2;

a1.show(); // prints 3
a2.show(); // prints 0
```

However, this magic is spoiled as soon as I introduce another template parameter in `A`, like this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N = 0>
class A
{
    ... // same content, no use of T
}
```

When I construct `A` passing any `T` like this, it does not compile anymore:

```
A<int> a1{data};
A<int> a2;
```

Compiler deduces `N=0` in all cases and cannot assign the input `std::array<int, 3>` to the deduced parameter in constructor `std::array<int, 0>`:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘A<int>::A(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
A<int> a1{data};

note: candidate: ‘A<T, N>::A(const Array&) [with T = int; long unsigned int N = 0; A<T, N>::Array = std::array<int, 0>]’
A(const Array& arr) : myArr{arr} {}

note:  no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::array<int, 3>’ to ‘const Array&’ {aka ‘const std::array<int, 0>&’}
A(const Array& arr) : myArr{arr} {}
```

Could anyone explain why this happens and if it has any solution?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you type `A<int>`, you specify all the template parameters, N is 0 by default. No deducing.

Comment: @S.M. That's it! I didn't realize. Then I believe there is no way to deduce `N` correctly, I need to pass `T` everywhere...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Partial class template argument deduction in C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57563594/partial-class-template-argument-deduction-in-c17)

Comment: @DavisHerring Thank you, it is a very close answer but I think I cannot make it work in my case. If I declare `template <typename T> class A -> A<T, 0>` for cases with `N=0` then I can remove the default value of `N` here `template <typename T, std::size_t N> class A`. That is great, it will allow `A<int> a2;`. However, I don't know how to declare cases where `N>0` without explicitly indicating `A<int, 3> a1{data};`. Is it possible or did I miss anything?

Comment: @Victor: I voted for the duplicate based on its explanation of the difficulty, not on the applicability of its workarounds.  That’s not to say that there can’t be any: in C++20, for instance, you may be able to use something like `wrapper<int>::alias a{data};`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deduction guides do not do partial matching.

Synthesized or not.

In the first case, the compiler synthesizes a deduction guide.

```
template<std::size_t N>
A(std::array<int,N>const&)->A<N>;
```

Once you pass any template parameters, deduction guides are not used.  No partial matching.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction for a decent description of what you called magic.

Write a make function if you want, or omit `int`.

As to why, probably reverse compatibility fears and the KISS principle.