# Deduce types of template-defined base class constructor parameters

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, ctad

I have a derived class, `Wrapper`, that inherits from a template-defined base class. I'd like to configure `Wrapper` so that if the base class has constructor parameters, `Wrapper`'s constructor also includes the base class's constructor params so that it can forward them to the base class constructor:

```cpp
struct Base1 {
  Base1(int) {}
};

struct Base2 {
  Base2(std::string) {}
};

// I'd like variadic template param `Args` to be deduced to a parameter
// pack matching a valid constructor for type T, if available.
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct Wrapper : public T {
  Wrapper(int, Args&&... v) : T(std::forward<Args>(v)...) {}
};

int main() {
  auto wrapper = Wrapper<Base1>(1, 2);
}
```

This example fails because the compiler is not deducing anything for `Args`, and so the resulting error is:

```
no matching function for call to ‘Wrapper<Base1>::Wrapper(int, int)’:
  candidate: ‘Wrapper<T, Args>::Wrapper(int, Args&& ...) [with T = Base1; Args = {}]’
  candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Is it possible to force the compiler to deduce the type(s) for the variadic template parameter `Args`, based on the deduced value of `T` and the parameters provided to `Wrapper` at construction?

Comment: Why are `Args` template parameters of the class instead of the constructor? Is this really what you want, that `Wrapper<Base1>(1, /*args*/)` will be a different type for any different set of types and value categories of `/*args*/`?

Comment: There is no class named `Derived`. You should correct the error message.

Comment: What about creating a `make_wrapper<T>(Args...args)` function`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having `Args` as a template parameter pack of the  class template, you can make the constructor a template as shown below:

```
//------------------v--------------->removed Args from here
template <typename T >
struct Wrapper : public T {
//--vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv----->made this a templated ctor
    template<typename... Args>
    Wrapper(int, Args&&... v) : T(std::forward<Args>(v)...) {}
};

int main() {
  auto wrapper = Wrapper<Base1>(1, 2); //works now
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o5ocP3bTj)

Comment: You're right, I'm not sure why I initially put this as a class template parameters instead of constructor parameters. This works now!

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are looking for is *Partial CTAD(Class Template Argument Deduction)*. At the moment, such behavior is not allowed in C++, and you must either provide all template parameters, or none.

For more relevant informations: [Partial class template argument deduction in C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57563594/partial-class-template-argument-deduction-in-c17)

---

A common pattern is to create a `make_XXX` function that will deduce the return type for you:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename ... Args>
auto make_wrapper(int, Args&& ... args)
{
    return Wrapper<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

And you will be able to call it like:

```cpp
auto wrapper = make_wrapper<Base1>(1, 2);
```

Here `wrapper` will be a `Wrapper<Base1, int>`.