# Cannot deduce template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I've the following code.

```cpp
template <size_t StateSize, typename VariableType>
class DifferentialEquation {
public:

  using StateType = std::array<VariableType, StateSize>;
  using Var = VariableType;

  // ...
};

template <size_t StateSize, typename VariableType>
class RungeKutta4 {
  // ...
};

template<
  template<size_t, class> class IntegratorStrategy,
  class VariableType,
  size_t StateSize
>
class Integrator {
public:

  using DE = DifferentialEquation<StateSize, VariableType>;
  using Strategy = IntegratorStrategy<StateSize, VariableType>;

public:

  Integrator(DE de) : m_de(de) {}
  
  // ...

private:

  DE m_de;
  Strategy m_strategy;
};
```

Basically, the `DifferentialEquation` represents a differential equation (you don't say?) and `DifferentialEquation::StateType` represent a state vector, that's simple a `std::array`.

`RungeKutta4` represents a method for integration that I want to use as integration strategy.

`Integrator` is the class that performs the integration. It must be aware of the `DifferentialEquation::StateType` since it uses it in order to perform calculus.

I can instantiate the classes with this code, that works:

```cpp
DifferentialEquation<2, double> deq;
Integrator<RungeKutta4, double, 2> integrator(deq);
```

The problem is that I'd like to remove redundant template arguments in `Integrator` template class instantiation, because `double` and `2` must be the same arguments used as template arguments of `DifferentialEquation`. So I'd like to write:

```cpp
DifferentialEquation<2, double> deq;
Integrator<RungeKutta4> integrator(deq);
```

The problem is that this code does not compile, and in Visual Studio I obtain following errors:

```
IntegrationTest.cpp(44): error C2955: 'Integrator': use of class template requires template argument list
  IntegrationTest.cpp(23): note: see declaration of 'Integrator'
IntegrationTest.cpp(44): error C3200: 'IntegratorStrategy<StateSize,VariableType>': invalid template argument for template parameter 'IntegratorStrategy', expected a class template
IntegrationTest.cpp(44): error C2955: 'Integrator': use of class template requires template argument list
  IntegrationTest.cpp(23): note: see declaration of 'Integrator'
IntegrationTest.cpp(44): error C2955: 'Integrator': use of class template requires template argument list
  IntegrationTest.cpp(23): note: see declaration of 'Integrator'
IntegrationTest.cpp(44): error C2639: trailing return type 'Integrator' of deduction guide should be a specialization of 'Integrator'
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Row 44 is where I write `Integrator<RungeKutta4> integrator(deq);`.

I've tried to use some template deduction guide but I obtained no results, since I never used them, for example with:

```
template<
  template<size_t, class> class IntegratorStrategy,
  class VariableType,
  size_t StateSize
>
Integrator(DifferentialEquation<StateSize, VariableType>) -> Integrator<
  IntegratorStrategy<StateSize, VariableType>,
  VariableType, StateSize
>;
```

But obviously is wrong.

How can I fix my code? What should I do in order to instantiate the `Integrator` class without repeating the template arguments needed by `DifferentialEquation`?

Comment: [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) is a whole or nothing.

Comment: Something along `Integrator integrator(RungeKutta4{}, deq);`, else there is still the `make_integrator` strategy.

Comment: See [Partial class template argument deduction in C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57563594/partial-class-template-argument-deduction-in-c17) and [CTAD  is an all or nothing process currently.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57563652/12002570)