# C++ deduction for variadic template arguments

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction

I have the following class interface:

```
template <typename D, typename... Cs>
struct Foo {
  
  Foo(int other_variable, Cs&&... cs) : 
    tuple {std::make_tuple(std::forward<Cs>(cs)...)} {
  }

  std::tuple<Cs...> tuple;
};
```

It fails to compile with the following code:

```
Foo<float> foo(1, 
  []()            { /* lambda type 1 */ },
  [](std::string) { /* lambda type 2 */ },
  [](int)         { /* lambda type 3 */ }
);
```

I had the impression that I need to provide a deduction guide but the following guide doesn't work:

```
template <typename D, typename... Cs> Foo(int, Cs&&...) -> Foo<D, Cs...>;
```

Comment: Reading around a bit, this is a duplicate of [c++ - C++17 class template partial deduction - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833630/c17-class-template-partial-deduction) -- there's no way except writing a helper `make_` function.

Comment: @Elliott Wrong link

Comment: @Elliott That's a different problem, see the error message.